# What's causing so much space in my div containers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create two divs with a heading that have a grey header that only have a small amount of padding.

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="small-grey-header">
                <p class="center-text">User Login</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="small-grey-header">
                <p class="center-text">Help Links</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css

```
.center-text{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.small-grey-header{
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: .5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The problem is that they look way to big and I'm not sure why.

Here is what I want[image: Image1]

And this is what im getting[image: image3]

Here is a the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/Ljsgtq0o/

I am using a grid system to set these side by side but I'm excluded it for simplicity. Even setting 1 pixel of padding on the divs is causing a huge amount of space. What am I doing wrong? Please note that I'm not concerned with the spacing between these two headings. I just want these headings to not be so large. They almost look like buttons.

Comment: That's because of the grid system. Inspect and find it out.

Comment: Please use the correct grid classes: `col-xs-6`

Comment: **Note:** There are no half Pixels. And Subpixel rounding can lead to ugly cases in some browsers.

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's not the issue. I didn't include the grid system in my fiddle and still got the same result. I'm not using bootstrap. The problem was p has a default margin. When set to 0 it fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a default `margin-bottom: 10px` on `p` from bootstrap. You can use another element for that text (like a `div`) or remove the margin from the `p`

And if you want them to be side-by-side, use the `col-size-#` class structure.

```css
.center-text {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.small-grey-header {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: .5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.small-grey-header p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="small-grey-header">
        <p class="center-text">User Login</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="small-grey-header">
        <p class="center-text">Help Links</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap though. And even when I exclude the grid system I am using this still happens.

Comment: @onTheInternet why are you using the bootstrap classes then? the answer is the same though, remove the `margin` on the `p` and the vertical spacing is reduced to the size of the text https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgRbVB

Comment: I'm using Simplegrid which has classes like bootstrap http://simplegrid.io/
And I'm only using the grid classes; I've removed all the font classes. I'm just confused why this happens in a fiddle where I'm getting same result but not including the framework. Does p have a default margin?

Comment: Yes, `p` has default margins applied by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add max-width property to small-grey-header class. For example:

> max-width:100px;

There you have shorter buttons.

If you want to have lower buttons you can simply edit height property, you don't have to use padding in this case and you can add line-height property.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljsgtq0o/2/

```
height: 25px;
line-height:25px;
```